# remix ide - The blue compilot icon is disabled. Do you know what to do?

Tags: javascript

The blue compilot icon is disabled. Do you know what to do?
The code was scraped from what a YouTuber posted as open source.
Is this because there is an error somewhere in the code?

We are trying to create 3 billion coins called kal.a based on bnb.

I scraped the code from an open source posted by a YouTuber.
However, the YouTuber is not a developer (it appears to have been written around July 2023 through chat gpt)

I have no development knowledge, so I don’t know where the error occurred.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.